# Move duplicates of a list within the list c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following list.

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>() 
{
    new Employee { EmpID = 1 , Name ="AC", DateofPresentation=newDateTime(2013,12,24),new List<Employee>{}                
    new Employee { EmpID = 1 , Name ="AC", DateofPresentation=newDateTime(2013,12,23),      new List<Employee>{}        
    new Employee { EmpID = 1 , Name ="AC", DateofPresentation=newDateTime(2013,12,22),new List<Employee>{}
```

}

I need it to be sorted like this. I have a table that shows specific employee data. I need to show items as a parent child like UI. So I need this child list.

```
 List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>() 
{
    new Employee
        { 
          EmpID = 1 , Name ="AC", DateofPresentation=newDateTime(2013,12,24),
          new list<Employee>
           { 
              new Employee { EmpID = 1 , Name ="AC"  DateofPresentation=newDateTime(2013,12,23), new List<Employee>{}
              new Employee { EmpID = 1 , Name ="AC", DateofPresentation=newDateTime(2013,12,22), new List<Employee>{}

           }  
}
```

I need to sort it by the most recent dated employee as parent, and the rest of employees in a list within

Can I achieve this in linq ?

Comment: Any attempt at solving this you can share with us? Please also post valid code, the code snippets in your question have no chance to compile.

Comment: Please rethink this, What you seem to have here is one employee that has three presentation dates, but what your structure suggests if you have one employee that is in charge of two employees of the same id and name with their own presentation date - This will then in turn get messy because the same sorting logic could then be applied to these sub employees

Comment: How should that compile? You haven't specified a property for the `new list<Employee>`(whatever a `list` is)
.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Please see my edits. Sorry fr missing the property. I need this this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a property ( i called it `Others`) to `Employee` to store the list

```
employees
    .GroupBy(x => x.EmpID)
    .Select(g => {
        var byPres = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateofPresentation).ToArray();
        var e = byPres.First();
        e.Others = byPres.Skip(1).ToList();
        return e;
    })
```

see demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/kRiMds

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code solution:

```
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>() 
    {
        new Employee() { EmpID = 1 , Name ="AC", DateofPresentation=new DateTime(2013,12,24)},
        new Employee() { EmpID = 1 , Name ="AC", DateofPresentation=new DateTime(2013,12,23)},
        new Employee() { EmpID = 1 , Name ="AC", DateofPresentation=new DateTime(2013,12,22)},
        new Employee() { EmpID = 1 , Name ="AC", DateofPresentation=new DateTime(2013,12,21)},
        new Employee() { EmpID = 2 , Name ="AC", DateofPresentation=new DateTime(2013,12,25)},
        new Employee() { EmpID = 2 , Name ="AC", DateofPresentation=new DateTime(2013,12,21)}
    };


    var list = employees.
        Select(i => new Employee()
        {
            EmpID = i.EmpID,
            Name = i.Name,
            DateofPresentation = i.DateofPresentation,
            Employees = employees.Where(j => i.EmpID == j.EmpID && j.DateofPresentation < i.DateofPresentation).ToList()
        }).
            GroupBy(x => x.EmpID).
            Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(i => i.DateofPresentation).First()).
            ToList();
```

Comment: It works, but the solution above seems to be better one